# Как убрать у console.table() поле index?

Tags: javascript

нужно убрать поле INDEX у метода table объекта console, снизу укажу код для которого всё это нужно:

```
function showHelpTable() {
  const gameCombinations = [
    { MOVE: 'ROCK', WINS: 'SCISSORS', LOSES: 'PAPER' },
    { MOVE: 'PAPER', WINS: 'ROCK', LOSES: 'SCISSORS' },
    { MOVE: 'SCISSORS', WINS: 'PAPER', LOSES: 'ROCK' },
  ]
  console.log('\nHelp:')
  console.table(gameCombinations)
}
```

Находил решение на стаке оно мне не особо понравилось, но работает, ниже скину его тоже)

```
function showHelpTable() {
  const gameCombinations = [
    { ХОД: 'КАМЕНЬ', ПОБЕДИТ: 'НОЖНИЦЫ', ПРОИГРАЕТ: 'БУМАГЕ' },
    { ХОД: 'БУМАГА', ПОБЕДИТ: 'КАМЕНЬ', ПРОИГРАЕТ: 'НОЖНИЦАМ' },
    { ХОД: 'НОЖНИЦЫ', ПОБЕДИТ: 'БУМАГУ', ПРОИГРАЕТ: 'КАМНЮ' },
  ]
  console.log('\nHelp:')
  const { Console } = require('console')
  const { Transform } = require('stream')
  function table(input) {
    const ts = new Transform({
      transform(chunk, enc, cb) {
        cb(null, chunk)
      },
    })
    const logger = new Console({ stdout: ts })
    logger.table(input)
    const table = (ts.read() || '').toString()
    let result = ''
    for (let row of table.split(/[\r\n]+/)) {
      let r = row.replace(/[^┬]*┬/, '┌')
      r = r.replace(/^├─*┼/, '├')
      r = r.replace(/│[^│]*/, '')
      r = r.replace(/^└─*┴/, '└')
      r = r.replace(/'/g, ' ')
      result += ${r}\n
    }
    console.log(result)
  }
  table(gameCombinations)
}
```

Такое решение слишком уж громоздкое, есть ли вариант всё сделать проще?
На выходе должна быть такая таблица:
[image: PS:такая таблица выходит при записи длинной функции с плохого примера]

PS:такая таблица выходит при записи длинной функции с плохого примера

А так таблица выглядит сейчас...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Console немного для другого был придуман. А что вы собственно хотите сделать?

Comment: в курсе, к сожалению нужно именно в консоли вывести таблицу с правилами игры камень, ножницы, бумага), тестовый проект, задание такое у меня, так то дай волю, то я бы не писал таким образом именно)
типа на стрессоустойчивость проверка)))

Comment: Никак. Оно там гвоздями прибито https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/console/constructor.js

Comment: Но, наверное, можно просто стащить код отсюда https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/main/lib/internal/cli_table.js

Comment: благодарю за помощь Алексей, у моей жены девичья фамилия Тен, все вы отзывчие)))